# How can I use a custom subclass of a Swing component? Do I need to install it to palette?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, javabeans, netbeans-plugins

How can I add NewJPanel, a Netbeans generated class which extends JPanel, to the palette for the GUI builder?

The goal is to be able to add a NewJPanel through the palette so that it has type NewJPanel rather than type JPanel.  However, it's not available through the palette as I would expect.

I'm following:

> To install via Palette Manager
>
> ```
> Open the Palette Manager from main menu: Tools | Palette Manager | Swing/AWT Components
> In the Palette Manager press button according to where the component comes from. The choices are: 
>
>     from an external JAR file
>     from a library defined in the IDE (always create a library if the components need more than one JAR)
>     from a NetBeans project
> ```

from the [Netbeans FAQ's](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormUsingCustomComponent).

This method doesn't work because the classes just aren't available for selection.

However, I was able to drag NewJPane onto the design view of NewJFrame where it was declared with the correct type of NewJPane (and not JPane).

[image]

Comment: Assuming you trying to add custom component to the palette through Netbeans project, Select your project folder and you shud be able to see your NewJpanel in the second step of the wizard. If not make sure NewJpanel has a no-args public constructor

Comment: It has such a constructor, and I am able to copy/paste or drag NewJPanel, it just doesn't add to the palette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your custom component to the matisse GUI palatte.

```
Build your project so the class file you want to use is part of the jar file
Open a java class that has a form, and switch to design mode. 3, Right click in the palatte and choose "palatte manager".
Choose the "add from jar" button to select your jar.
Choose the class you made, and add it to your palatte.
```

Now your panel is known to netbeans, and you can drag it into new panels.

Comment: what I found was that if you tinker with the component before adding it then it won't work.  However, if you add it first, then you can tinker with it quite a bit.  Pardon, need to re-read my question and your answer.  Bonus points for answering an old question!